# asset.getUrl() not correct: missing subfolder directory

Tags: plugin-development, assets, database

I created a new asset source/folder called "my-assets".

It has an entry in the DB in "craft_assetsources" with the id=10, path="my_base_folder/assets/my-assets/" and url="/assets/my-assets/",

plus an entry in the "craft_assetfolders" with the id=27, sourceID=10 and name="my-assets".

Then I've created a subfolder called "my-images", which only has an entry in "craft_assetfolders" with id=28, sourceID=10 and path="my-images/".

When I use the myImage.asset.getUrl() on an image from that subfolder, I get the url "/assets/my-assets/myImage.jpg" instead of "/assets/my-assets/my-images/myImage.jpg", which obviously results in the image not being found.

Any ideas why this happens and especially how to fix it?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Go to setting, then try to click Update Assets Indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Because of the lack of time I already changed the my-images folder to directly be located in the root.
So I couldn't try your suggestion, but I will next time, thanks ;)